# Excel formula to return any matched strings from 2 different cells

Tags: excel, match

I want to build a formula that will return true/false if 1 or more matches is found between two cells.

The two cells are formatted in the exact same way i.e values separated with semi colons or just a word if only one value exists. The values will also be the exact same in both cells i.e Case sensitivity.

Here is my formula/attempt and is returning true in this instance but for some reason there are examples when false is returned when it should be true.

Guidance much appreciated.

[image: Image of formula]

Comment: 1. You should show example which doesn't work. 2. You split with ";" and not with "; ", so it will look for " Brocolli" (with space before) in G4 and in case it is in start of a string it will be false. 3. peas will give false positive in chickpeas. Is it a desired result or not?

Comment: Try =IF(SUM(MAP(TEXTSPLIT(C4,"; "), LAMBDA(z, SUM(N(z=TEXTSPLIT(G4,"; "))))))>0,TRUE)

Comment: This has worked perfectly thank you. Was to do with semi colon spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(SUM(MAP(TEXTSPLIT(C4,"; "), LAMBDA(z, SUM(N(z=TEXTSPLIT(G4,"; "))))))>0,TRUE)
```

Result:

[image]

Or don't use `IF` and just leave:

```
=SUM(MAP(TEXTSPLIT(C4,"; "), LAMBDA(z, SUM(N(z=TEXTSPLIT(G4,"; "))))))
```

To get matches count:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative without `LAMBDA`:

```
=LET(ζ,TEXTSPLIT(C4&"; "&G4,,"; "),(ROWS(ζ)-ROWS(UNIQUE(ζ,,1)))/2)
```